# How to solve Token issues for Android Application in Jmeter

Tags: android, jmeter, performance-testing

Thread Name: Thread Group 1-3
Sample Start: 2018-08-07 15:02:49 IST
Load time: 228
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 228
Size in bytes: 401
Sent bytes:347
Headers size in bytes: 312
Body size in bytes: 89
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 403
Response message: Forbidden

"Status":200,"Response":"Failure","Data":{"fail":"Forbidden. Token expired","status":0}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the majority of cases you cannot just replay what you captured using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) without performing [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) - the process of identifying dynamic parameters in the previous response, extracting them and saving into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and replacing recorded hard-coded values with these variables.

So your test plan should look like:

- First [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

  - [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract the token and save it into a variable
- Second HTTP Request where you should replace recorded token with the JMeter Variable from the previous step.